# Show two measurement units on axis ticks in ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

How it is possible (if at all) to show two alternative units on axis ticks in ggplot2?
What I would like to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty confident this functionality doesn't exist in `ggplot2`. You might be able to get there with a bunch of hack work, but I guess it would be ugly...

Comment: There is not an official implentation. But look at [this](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2), perhaps you can modify it to your needs

Comment: @bgbg is it yes/no answer?

Comment: @agstudy no it's not. I have edited the  question accordingly

Comment: @Arun I haven't downvote but I think , the downvote because the Op don't show what he has tried.

Comment: possibly of interest: [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2-dev/JkJU5CLBkQw)

Comment: @agstudy Yes, I understand. However, it's a bit hard to show what you've done when you're asking for a feature that's not directly implemented/straightforward in `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Roland, I think it's quite different from what the OP is expecting. They're range bars denoting unit equivalence. However, thanks for that link as it might come handy someday.

Comment: @Arun at least you prepare data for others..you tell them that you have find this but it is not what you want..you show some effort.. Whatever the question is interesting.

Comment: @Arun Did you read to the bottom? Kohske created a `guide_axis`, which even lets you specify the transformation.

Comment: @Roland, yes indeed, read only the first post and got carried away by the title. beg your pardon.

Comment: For what it's worth it looks like Kohske's github branch is now incompatible with the latest version of `plyr` ... dependency hell.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like a broken record on SO with these questions... @bgbg the 'lattice' and 'ggplot2' packages are wrappers that only offer a certain amount of flexibility.  If you really want to solve this easily and without hacks or workarounds, you should probably consider going directly to the source and using the base 'grid' package which has unit conversion built in.  If you are interested, I can code up an example, but if you're stuck on the 'ggplot2' package, it's going to take more fiddling than I think it's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hacky way of doing that:

```
d = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = rnorm(20, 5, 5))

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:20, seq(2.54, 20, 2.54)),
                     labels = c(1:20, paste0("\n", 1:as.integer(20/2.54), "\""))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: yep, won't work for a publication, but good enough for my needs. Thank you