# Creating Multiple y-axes scales (or alternatives?) using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

I'm trying to display two different kinds of information in a graphic.  Here's a MWE, and then I'll explain:

```
library(ggplot2)
p = 1:10/10-.05
X = matrix(0,nrow=100,ncol=10)
for( i in 1:10 ) X[,i] = rbinom(100,1,p[i])
d = data.frame(X)
coef = runif(10,min=1,max=2)
d$Y = X %*% coef + rnorm(100)
plot( Y ~ X1, data=d )
fit = glm( Y ~ ., data=d )
coeff.df = data.frame( summary(fit)$coeff )
coeff.df$Count = c(NA,apply(d, 2, sum)[-11] )
coeff.df$Name = row.names(coeff.df)
coeff.df$Count.Scaled =
    coeff.df$Count/max(coeff.df$Count,na.rm=T)*max(coeff.df$Estimate)
ggplot( coeff.df, aes(x=Name) ) + geom_point(aes(y=Estimate)) +
    geom_bar(aes(weight=Count.Scaled),alpha=.3)
```

So, I want to convey two things in the plot: the coefficient from the model as well as another measure of volume or proportion.  Now my problem: I want two axes so that I can interpret the coefficient as well as the volume (and, in this case, I had to hack the volume numbers so they scaled cleanly to the data).

I've heard that ggplot currently doesn't have the functionality to display two axes like this, is that correct?  What would be a good way to represent data like this?

Comment: This is a pretty common issue - have a look at the discussion here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247235/show-two-measurement-units-on-axis-ticks-in-ggplot2) especially @LucianoSelzer's link (http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2)

Comment: Thanks alexwhan!  Not as pretty of a solution as I was hoping for, but I think it'll work...

Comment: @JoshBrowning does it matter if you use a lattice solution?

Comment: I'd really like to stick with ggplot2 as all of the other graphics in my presentation use this package.  Is lattice a separate plotting package altogether, or does it work with ggplot2?